# Spring Integration + send 2 events to kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a message gateway which receives in an input channel an http Json request.

I want to send 2 events to kafka as part this same request, one event for received and one event for processed.

What is the best way to achieve this with Spring Integration?

This is how I did it and it works but not sure if there is a better approach:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processMessage() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel")
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r.recipient("inputChannel2")
                                    .recipient("inputChannel3"))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendReceived(MessageTransformer messageTransformer) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel2")
            .transform(messageTransformer)
            .handle( this.kafkaMessageHandler() )
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendProcessed(MessageTransformer2 messageTransformer) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel3")
            .transform(messageTransformer)
            .handle( this.kafkaMessageHandler() )
            .get();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you do is OK. Another way to achieve the same goal is to use a `poublishSubscribeChannel` instead:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

Also you may consider to have a single configuration for the Kafka message handler and reuse a channel for it from those two distribution flows.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way it does the job:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subscribersFlow(MessageTransformer messageTransformer, MessageTransformer2 messageTransformer2) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("inputChannel")
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .transform(messageTransformer)
                            .handle(  this.kafkaMessageHandler() )
                    )
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .transform(messageTransformer2)
                            .handle( this.kafkaMessageHandler() )
                    )
            )
            .get();
}
```